# How can I define the tracery in my script to generate random sentences?

Tags: javascript, html

After struggling getting the data from an independent tracery library stored in the server where my site is hosted I decided to use another approach with the following code but it was unsuccessful since I wasn't able to generate the desired result which is nothing but a random sentence every time I load the page:

```
    <html>
<head>

<script defer src="js/tracery/tracery.js"></script>

<script defer src="js/tracery/tracery.min.js"></script>

<script defer src="js/tracery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>

<script>

var data = {

  "origin": "#salutation#, #name#",

  "salutation": ["Hi", "Good morning", "Good evening", "Good night"],

  "name": ["John", "Mary", "Peter", "Anne"]

};

var grammar = tracery.createGrammar(data);

var sentence = grammar.flatten("#origin#");

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sentence;

</script>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the following error on the browser's console: "message 7  Uncaught ReferenceError: tracery is not defined at agronobot.html:17:15".

I called all those files but I think the only one I needed was tracery.min.js and the console said tracery complete but as well but as I said before I couldn't see the desired outcome when I load the page.

Comment: Your inline script is running before your `<script>` tags have loaded, so `tracery` hasn’t been declared yet.

Comment: *I committed a error closing the head tag while I was pasting the code on the question but I corrected the tag closing after the script that is before the body tag and I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the error, just put `<script>` library inside `<head>` tag and ensure you import the jquery library first.

**EDIT**: Instead of importing local `tracery.js`, you can try importing online version of that :
https://tracery.io/editor/js/tracery/tracery.js

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://tracery.io/editor/js/tracery/tracery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
     <script>
        var data = {
            "origin": "#salutation#, #name#",
            "salutation": ["Hi", "Good morning", "Good evening", "Good night"],
            "name": ["John", "Mary", "Peter", "Anne"]
        };
        var grammar = tracery.createGrammar(data);
        var sentence = grammar.flatten("#origin#");
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sentence;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I applied the corrections but it doesn't work still